# How to convert unix timestamp to NSData object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, nsdata

I'm using Core Bluetooth to write to a peripheral. I would like to send the current unix timestamp to the sensor, and I have attempted to do that like so:

```
// Write timestamp to paired peripheral
NSDate*           measureTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter*  usDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSLocale*         enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[usDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'"];
[usDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[usDateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];  // Should force 24hr time regardless of settings value

NSString *dateString = [usDateFormatter stringFromDate:measureTime];
NSDate* startTime = [usDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

uint32_t timestamp = [startTime timeIntervalSince1970];
NSData *timestampData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&timestamp length:sizeof(timestamp)]; // <- Troublemaker
[pairedPeripheral writeValue:timestampData forCharacteristic:currentCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Here's the issue:

My 32 bit timestamp returns the correct value, however when I convert it into NSData, the peripheral reads it as a 24 hour clock value like this: "16:42:96"

Where am I making the error?

**EDIT**

I have modified the code to get rid of NSDateFormatter, as someone has mentioned that it is unnecessary. I still seem to be getting the same result:

```
// Write timestamp to paired peripheral
NSDate*           measureTime = [NSDate date];
uint64_t timestamp = [measureTime timeIntervalSince1970];
NSData *timestampData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&timestamp length:sizeof(timestamp)]; // <- Troublemaker
[pairedPeripheral writeValue:timestampData forCharacteristic:currentCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "peripheral reads"? Where do you get "16:42:96"?

Comment: When I use the Light Blue to read the characteristic's stored value, I view that number "16:42:96" but what I really want is the unix timestamp which is "149562...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused. What you're sending to the peripheral is an integer number of seconds since 1970. That's a reasonable way to send a Unix timestamp, but it is not a time in 24 hour format, it is an integer.

You will need to change your code to use a uint64_t or uint32_t since Unix timestamps are much larger numbers than will fit in a 32 bit integer. (I suggest using uint64_t.)

(See @DonMag's comment for sample timestamp values, like 1491580283)

How you display that time once it is received by the peripheral is a separate question, and the question that you should really be asking.

Note that you may run into problems sending an int as binary data if the peripheral has different "endian-ness" than your iOS device. you might want to convert the timestamp integer to a string and send that in order to avoid the endian-ness problem.

Comment: So you're saying that the peripheral reading it as a 24 hour time is an entirely separate issue. However, when I convert my 32-64bit integer into an NSData object the hex value once converted to a decimal value does not represent the standard timestamp value format

Comment: When I print the description of my NSData object, I get the following: <fcc6e758> Once I convert this hex value to an integer, it does not show the correct timestamp value

Comment: Check the byte ordering... what is the "hex value" if you set `uint64_t timestamp = 1;` ?

Comment: Setting the the timestamp to 1 returns <01000000 00000000> as the hex value

Comment: right - now punch that into a hex-to-dec converter... what's the value? I get `72057594037927936` which is certainly not equal to `1`.

Comment: Ahhh you're right. Ok, so I guess the question now is how can I convert my hex value to get the int value to ensure I'm sending the proper time?

Comment: That's what we're trying to tell you... you are *already* sending the proper time. The difference is how the "other side" displays it. The strings "4:15 PM" and "16:15" are displaying the same time - just different *display formats*.

Comment: I am so sorry, thank you so much for the clarification. I guess converting my hex value to a decimal was the part that was completely throwing me off, but converting it back to an integer in Xcode yields the result I want. Again, so sorry

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `NSDateFormatter`, unless you're planning on sending a string representation to the peripheral.

From the [Apple Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate):

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).

With that in mind, you can use `measureTime` as-is, and get the same result:

```
uint32_t timestamp = [measureTime timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Without knowing specifics about the peripheral, it's impossible to say why it's showing a 24-hour value.

If I were to hazard a guess, I would expect there to be another characteristic / value you need to modify first, in order to switch it to a different format (if that's even possible).

Comment: I seem to be getting the same result- timestamp is correct but when I pass it into my NSData object, the result is: <f8b3e758> which if you convert the hex -> decimal is the wrong Unix timestamp.

Comment: @FaisalSyed - you are sending the number of seconds since 1970 to the Bluetooth device. At that point, it has nothing to do with format - or even "timestamp". It's simply a number. For example, right now, if I run your code, the value of `timestamp` is 1491580283. How your Bluetooth device displays it (or how another bluetooth reader displays it) is totally irrelevant to what you are doing.